# :selected condition in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I want to have `:selected`condition for v-for loop

My code is:

```
<select id="lstCategories" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose from drop down</option>
    <option v-for="category in lstCategories" :value="category.id" :key="category.id">{{ category.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I want something like this:

```
<option v-for="category in lstCategories" 
        :value="category.id" :key="category.id" 
        :selected="this.myData.category_ids.includes(category.id)">
  {{ category.name }}
</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `myData` is a part of component's state, you should just drop `this` from that expression, as all the template expressions are evaluated against `data` anyway:

```
<option v-for="category in lstCategories" 
        :value="category.id" :key="category.id" 
        :selected="myData.category_ids.includes(category.id)">
  {{ category.name }}
</option>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkuyfqj9/).

Comment: Do you have a solution for sort `lstCategories` according to `myData.category_ids`  ? For example  myData.category_ids = [3,1,2] - and lstCategories = [5,4,3,2,1] . then sorted array equal to [3,1,2,5,4]